# Spotify Apps - Getting Playlist Tracks

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm developing a Spotify app and want to get the tracks for a Playlist. There's the function `playlist.tracks` but that seems to be cached and gets the wrong list of tracks. It's also supposed to be slow and not recommended to be used in the API documentation. But what other option do I have to get a Playlist's tracks? At the moment I'm using `playlist.tracks` once and informing my back-end of the track list.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure you've checked the API recently? ([here](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/c49e02a392.html))

Comment: Yes, could you be more specific about what I should be looking at? That's only referencing the `playlist.tracks` function.

Comment: No sorry, I was just checking to see you were using the latest version. It does seem strange that they opted for a `tracks` property rather than a `getTracks()` method. What does the `toString()` method return? It might return a JSON string with the track info, which you could parse.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I've been bitten by that already! I think `tracks` is just an alias to a function, since I doubt they'd be concerned about the performance of variable access! `toString()` has only been returning an error for me, annoyingly. But the error it returns references `name` so I can only imagine it's outputting the name only.

Comment: As the error is referencing `name` then it would seem that your `Playlist` object has not been instantiated (see the constructor line in API), or at least, not instantiated properly. Hence the error on `toString()` and the returning of a wrong/blank tracklist.  Sorry I can't be more specific but I've never used the Spotify API!

Comment: Interestingly [this](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/44c5f339c3.html) method is deprecated....

Comment: Yeah, I saw that deprecated method. I don't think it's been instantiated wrongly, as I can actually access the `name` property directly fine. Suggesting there's a bug in `toString()`. The list it's getting back is just out of date from what I can see, suggesting a caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the 1.0 API:

```
require([
  '$api/models'
], function (models) { 

 var addList = function(list) {
    list.load('tracks').done(function(list) {
        list.tracks.snapshot().done(function(trackSnapshot){
            var tracks = trackSnapshot.toArray();
            for(var i=0; i<tracks.length; i++) {
                addTrack(tracks[i]);
            }
        });
    });
 }

 var addTrack = function(track) {
    track.load('name','artists').done(function(track) {
        var artists = track.artists;
        var artistsList = [];
        for (var i=0; i<artists.length; i++) {
            artistsList.push(artists[i].name);
        }
        // Print out info if desired
        var addedTrackRow = document.createElement('p');
        addedTrackRow.innerHTML = "Added track: " + artistsList.join(', ') + ' - ' + track.name;
        document.getElementById('addedTracks').appendChild(addedTrackRow);

    });
 }

 exports.addList = addList;
 exports.addTrack = addTrack;
}

// Example of use:
addList(models.Playlist.fromURI(...))
addTrack(models.Track.fromURI(...))
```

I've tested it as used above, and it works.

I spent some time looking for an answer to this myself, and I also were looking for how to access tracks within a list even though it's explained in the [tutorial-app available on github](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/) under the "Metadata"-section; "Get metadata from an artist, album, track or playlist".

I hope this is usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small sample :

```
pl = new m.Playlist();
alb = m.Album.fromURI(uri, function(album) { 
   pl.name = album.name;
   $.each(album.tracks,function(index,track){
      pl.add(m.Track.fromURI(track.uri));   
   });
```

Hope it could help....

```
$.each(pl.data.all(),function(i,track){ myAwesomePlaylist.add(track); });
```

where pl is the playlist

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. I'm trying to get the tracks for a Playlist, not get the tracks for an album into a playlist. I have the URI of the playlist and need the tracks within it. `playlist.tracks` is returning the wrong tracks for one of my playlists. The API actually recommends you avoid using `playlist.tracks` anyway, so I wondered if there was another way of getting them.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are rigth, I misunderstood...
    $.each(pl.data.all(),function(i,track){           myAwesomePlaylist.add(track);
        }); where pl is the playlist

Comment: Well, that's returning the same list, but as URIs rather than as `Track` objects. I wish Spotify would make it clear which is the preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Playlist` implements the interface `Collection`. So you can invoke the function `get` over playlist object in a loop to get all the tracks. Example code:

```
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<models.library.starredPlaylist.length;i++)
{
    var track = models.library.starredPlaylist.get(i);
}
```