# Spotify API - Getting the track URI of every track in a playlist

Tags: javascript, spotify

If I have an existing playlist (therefore a playlist URI), is there a way I can get the track URI for each track in that playlist using the Spotify API? I've had a read through the documentation but I'm struggling.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mh, maybe you can use sourcecode of the html page where the playlist is posted?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it loading the `tracks` property of an [`Album`](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/models-album.html) instance. Here you have an example that prints the uri of the tracks on an Album, using the 1.x API:

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
  var album = models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:0hljn4caZCf6xPILpLDJkB');
  album.load('tracks').done(function(a) {
    a.tracks.snapshot().done(function(snapshot) {
      for (var i = 0, l = snapshot.length; i < l; i++) {
        var track = snapshot.get(i);
        console.log(track.uri);
      }
    }).fail(function(){
        console.error('Error retrieving snapshot');
    });
  }).fail(function(){
      console.error('Error retrieving album information');
  });
});
```

If you have used previously the 0.X API, check out the [Snapshots section in the upgrade guide](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/upgrade-guide/1.0.0#Snapshots), which explains it more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

The [playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/models-playlist.html) object contains a list of the tracks as a collection . [Here is the same question answered in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362454/spotify-apps-getting-playlist-tracks).